# Why do I get this <br> element in a contenteditble div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div element that looks like this

```
<div id="test" contenteditable="true" style="height: 17px;">
</div>
```

When I do `$("#test").html()`, I'd expect to see an empty string returned, but in fact, it gives me `<br>`.

Why would there be a `<br>` even if I haven't put any there in the div?

Edit: Actually, in between the div tag, I have a Struts2 property tag which outputs a value but this value populated in the backend is empty so I was not expecting to see `<br>` there.

Comment: I [cannot reproduce it](http://jsbin.com/xadovaciku/edit?html,js,console).

Comment: Can't be reproduced, cause that's not the actual HTML you have.

Comment: Try putting the closing div on the same line as the div opening.

Comment: It's a line breaking, that is visible on editable content. Maybe you are treating that line breaking like a `<br>`. But the line break exists

Comment: @luissimo He doesn't complaint about the line feed, he claims to find a `<br>` tag.

Comment: Some browsers will put a br tag into the element when it is empty so there is a way to add text. What browser are you using? Any WYSIWYG libraries?

Comment: @epascarello IE 11 and no other libraries.

Comment: That is what IE does.

Comment: Man people, happy to close when it is reproducible when you use the right browser. IE renders a BR tag when an element that is contenteditable is empty.

Comment: @epascarello you are very right, sir. I've tried in Chrome and I did not see the <br> tag.

Comment: I cannot reproduce it either in my IE11 copy (Windows 10 x64). Whatever, I've cast a re-open vote, but please edit the relevant information into the question so it's useful for others in the future.

Answer (score 0):

It's look like strange issue, As far my experience it can be due to these stuff

1. It may be html tags are not closed
2. You may have some browser extension which some time do these type weird stuff

so try to disable all extension and check all html tags also  try in incognito  mode after disable extension, I think it may help you for debugging this issue.

Answer (score -1):

https://jsfiddle.net/47r6p89r/

There is space between `<div ...>` and `</div>`.
Also spaces will be detect by HTML but only one by one. The weird thing is that you got

```
<br>
```

as output I just got nothing as in the fiddle.

Here like in my fiddle you can detect if `#test` is empty if not you can see the result.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($('#test').html() !== "")
    $('#console').text($('#test').html());
  else
    $('#console').text('empty');
});
```